# Cannot add the item to shopping cart with exception - A non-numeric value encountered in

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, cart, addtocart, shopping-cart

I am learning Magento and getting this error: `Cannot add the item to shopping cart.`

I am stucked here anyone can help

**Exception.log**

```
Exception: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered  in \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Abstract.php on line 466 in \app\code\local\Mage\Core\functions.php:246
Stack trace:
#0 \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Abstract.php(466): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'A non-numeric v...', 'E:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 466, Array)
#1 \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Abstract.php(432): Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract->_getPerorderPrice('7.95', 'F', '')
#2 \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php(85): Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee('7.95')
#3 \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Shipping.php(209): Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#4 \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Shipping.php(129): Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping->collectCarrierRates('flatrate', Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#5 \app\code\local\Amasty\Shiprestriction\Model\Shipping\Shipping.php(9): Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#6 \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address.php(944): Amasty_Shiprestriction_Model_Shipping_Shipping->collectRates(Object(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request))
#7 \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address.php(875): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->requestShippingRates()
#8 \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Shipping.php(155): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectShippingRates()
#9 \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address.php(1013): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#10 \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php(1331): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()
#11 \app\code\local\Idev\OneStepCheckout\Model\Sales\Quote.php(27): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()
#12 \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php(461): Idev_OneStepCheckout_Model_Sales_Quote->collectTotals()
#13 \app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php(240): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#14 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#15 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#16 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 \app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 \index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

mmm

Just a try... go to **Backoffice > Sales > Shipping methods** and fill 0 (instead of empty value, as I suppose it'd be) in **Handling Fee** parameter for Flat Rate method

Answer (score 0):

app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php

```
protected function _getPerorderPrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee)
    {
        if ($handlingType == self::HANDLING_TYPE_PERCENT) {
            return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + ($cost * $this->_numBoxes * $handlingFee / 100);
        }

        if(isset($handlingFee) && $handlingFee){
            return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + ($handlingFee);
        }
        return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes);
    }
```